# How to use attachFile on svg element in Cypress

Tags: svg, cypress

I am trying to attach a file in chat box by clicking on attach icon, which is a svg element. Below is the HTML :

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 64 64" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
<path class="icon-attach_svg__fill" d="M55.334 28.926l-24.506 23.34c-5.222 4.973-13.74 4.973-18.962 0-5.149-4.903-5.149-12.797 0-17.7l24.506-23.34c3.138-2.988 8.278-2.988 11.416 0 3.064 2.919 3.064 7.594 0 10.513L23.255 45.077c-1.055 1.005-2.815 1.005-3.87.001-.98-.933-.98-2.39 0-3.325l22.64-21.535a2.667 2.667 0 00-3.676-3.864L15.709 37.89a7.578 7.578 0 00-.001 11.05c3.113 2.966 8.11 2.966 11.224 0l24.533-23.338c5.272-5.021 5.272-13.217 0-18.238-5.197-4.95-13.573-4.95-18.77 0L8.187 30.704c-7.356 7.005-7.356 18.419 0 25.424 7.281 6.935 19.036 6.935 26.318 0l24.506-23.34a2.666 2.666 0 10-3.678-3.862z" fill="#000" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
```

I am using below code to get element and attach file.

```
cy.xpath("//*[name()='path' and contains(@class,'icon-attac')]").attachFile("Automation.pdf")
```

Interestingly, Cypress passes this test but attached file is not displayed in UI.

I tried manually and checked. The file is displayed in UI, but while automating using cypress it is not present.

Is there any other way to handle svg element for attachFile ?

Comment: Are you applying an assertion after the upload to verify that the upload was successful.

Comment: @AlapanDas Yes. I kept an assertion. It is failing after being timed out. Are there any chances it is happening because third party app is used to attach files and send messages ?